# Saving object state using xml Serializer. Recommend approach for getting node name from property or hardcoded string?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

We are trying to save state of our object using XML serializer. For discussion assume object to be like:

```
Class Program
{
    public string Char1 {get; set;}
    public XMLNode Serialize (XmlDocument doc)
    {
        var node = document.CreateElement("Mod")
        node.SetAttribute("Char1", Char1.ToString());
    }
}
```

Here we are getting the value of property Char1 and trying to write it in a node with name Char1.

Is it better to have the node name "Char1" be derived from Char1 property using reflection. But this could result in changing the XML document often when property name is changed.

If property name is changed and the string is not updated then the value in xml document will not match the context of that field.

What approach is preferable?

Please suggest if there is any other better approach to avoid magic strings while writing xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer following way: Create a class which holds all your data you want wo serialize. Then create an instance of the XmlSerializer like this

```
xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    using (var xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
    {
        xmlTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Intented;
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(myObject.GetType());
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, myObject);
        xmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace = true;
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(stringWriter.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: In the context of the question, what you are suggesting is to get the node name from the property itself, Is my understanding correct ?